# C# - Regex subtitle file (.srt) to get text content?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a srt file

```
1
00:00:07,000 --> 00:00:09,000
Time to amaze the world..
create by Hazy

2
00:00:11,000 --> 00:00:12,200
show them

3
00:00:15,000 --> 00:00:16,500
an impossible feat
```

i want to get text content

```
Time to amaze the world..
create by Hazy,
show them,
an impossible feat
```

My regex:

```
string[] souceSrt = Regex.Split(inputText.Text, @"\n*\d+\n\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d --> \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d\n");
```

but it's not working. What should i do??

Comment: Shouldn't you have multiline flag somewhere in using your regex?

Comment: I think it might be easier to use `File.ReadAllLines` and then skip the lines you're not interested in, rather than splitting via a Regex.

Comment: I don't understand why some people have downvoted this post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach wasn't bad, I think your pattern doesn't work because of newlines (that are probably CRLF):

```
(?:\r?\n)*\d+\r?\n\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} --> \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\r?\n
```

Note that your first approach is safer than searching all lines that contains letters (imagine a character that says "how old are you?")

Answer (score 4):

using [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net)

```
string strRegex = @"^.*([a-zA-Z]).*$";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline);

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
   if (myMatch.Success)
   {
     //grab line
   }
}
```

unless there's something I've missed, the lines you don't want will never have an alphabetic character in  them.

Comment: This solution is only applicable for English subtitle .what if we have other language like Arabic or Polish subtitle.

Comment: `what if we have other language like Arabic or Polish subtitle` well I'd say this solution probably would not work most of the time then.

Answer (score 0):

**A solution to parse an SRT without RegEx**

Create a class to Deserialize the SRT

```
public class SrtContent
 {
     public string Text { get; set; }
     public string StartTime { get; set; }
     public string EndTime { get; set; }
     public string Segment { get; set; }
 }
```

Now here is the method that will parse the SRT

```
private static void ParseSRT(string srtFilePath)
 {
       var fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(srtFilePath);
       if (fileContent.Length <= 0)
           return;

       var content = new List<SrtContent>();
       var segment = 1;
       for (int item = 0; item < fileContent.Length; item++)
       {
                if (segment.ToString() == fileContent[item])
                {
                    content.Add(new SrtContent
                    {
                        Segment = segment.ToString(),
                        StartTime = fileContent[item + 1].Substring(0, fileContent[item + 1].LastIndexOf("-->")).Trim(),
                        EndTime = fileContent[item + 1].Substring(fileContent[item + 1].LastIndexOf("-->") + 3).Trim(),
                        Text = fileContent[item + 2]

                    });
                    // The block numbers of SRT like 1, 2, 3, ... and so on
                    segment++;
                    // Iterate one block at a time
                    item += 3;
                }
         }    
 }
```

Comment: Having code like `for(...; item++){...; item+=3;}` is a really poor way of stepping four lines per iteration. The question shows blocks with various numbers of lines, so stepping in fours will not work. This code does not extract both lines in block 1.